# angularjs dashboard based on topic

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, queue

How to accomplish this ?.

I have an angularjs dashboard that needs to display 3 types of metrics(m1,m2,m3).

A third party source will dump the data to different topics (m1-topic1,m2-topic2,m3-topic3).

In angular dashboard I need to show the data m1,m2,m3 .

Angularjs is linked to web api..

Here is my approach . Is this the correct approach

Create a $watch in angular controller and subscribe to topic ever time and pull the data .

The topics are located in azure queue.

Any idea whats the best way to implement this ?.

Comment: "The topics are located in azure queue." Do you mean Azure Storage Queues? Because these do not support topics. Maybe you mean Service Bus, which does support topics ???

Comment: yes i mean Service Bus